# How to solve webdriver issue

Tags: python

i'm getting a problem of TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in my code and i can't find any solution

i've tried evrething but webdriver isn't working

```
from selenium import webdriver
new=2
url='https://energyiptv.net/en/iptv-testline-anfordern/'
webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get('https://energyiptv.net/en/iptv-testline-anfordern/')
id_box = driver.find_element_by_id('wpforms-1054-field_0')
```

i expect to find id in an url and then input words on it

Comment: Could you include the full error?

Comment: `webbrowser` is not defined.  This is not your real code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Also, saying "it isn't working" does not help much.  What is it actually doing, and what did you want instead?

Comment: @JohnGordon i'm new in  programming also this is my first upload to this website.  Your comment really means a lot to me thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `webdriver.chrome()` you have to call `webdriver.Chrome()`.The former is a module, the letter is the actual class you mean to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

so i've tried to fix my problem depending on your solution and it worked !!!

In details i deleted `webbrowser` and changed `webdriver.chrome()` to `webdriver.Chrome()`